# How to handle common methods in Multi Module Scala Gradle project

Tags: scala, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have written a scala project by using Gradle as build tool with below folder structure

```
Root Dir
   |->settings.gradle
   |->data
   |   |->common
   |   |     |->config.scala
   |   |     |->method.scala
   |   |->data_offline
   |   |     |->build.gradle
   |   |     |->src/main/scala
   |   |           |->com.example.data.offline
   |   |                         |-> Main.scala
   |   |     
   |   |->data_online
   |         |->build.gradle
   |         |->src/main/scala
   |               |->com.example.data.online
   |                             |-> Main.scala
   |->info
       |->info_offline
            |->build.gradle
            |->src/main/scala
                   |->com.example.info.offline
                                 |-> Main.scala
```

I want to use files config.scala and method.scala in Main classes of data_offline and data_online modules. I am still doubtful like how to achieve it with Gradle. Seeking for Any suggestion to achieve this in same format or any other way? My effort is to reduce code duplication in different functions and also I am new to Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the docs to know how [Declare Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html). You need to include your projects in the `settings.gradle` file and in the `build.gradle` of the project that will depend on the other one add

- `/settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'the-name-of-your-project'
include 'common', 'data_online', 'data_offline'
```

- `/data_offline/build.gradle` (data_online should be similar)

```
dependencies {
    implementation project('common')
}
```

Comment: not sure what is exactly the issue. edit your post and show a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). also add details on what's the expected behaviour and what is happening? if you get error messages add them too.